# How to get all emits after a debounce

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an Observable chain that emits data in groups.

for example

1-2-3-4-5-----------1-2-3-5-6------------5-3-2-1-9------....

each number is an emit, and what I need is the following:

[1,2,3,4,5]----------[1,2,3,5,6]---------[5,3,2,1,9]----....

so in this case instead of 15 emits of an Integer.
I will get 3 emits of an Array of integers.

the difference between connected emits is usually less than 100 milliseconds, and the difference between different groups is usually more than a few minutes.
so I thought of doing some combination of Debounce, and scan to convert the emits into an Array, but I didn't find anything that worked for me.

is there some nifty RxJava2 operator that does the trick for me?

I have done the following

```java
        List<IncomeMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        incomeMessageSubject.doOnNext(messages::add)
                .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(incomeMessage -> {
                    List<IncomeMessage> tempMessages = new ArrayList<>(messages);
                    messages.clear();
                    return tempMessages;
                })
                .subscribe();
```

but I was wondering if there is a solution that is built in as an operator and does not require having a list that I need to manually manage.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in operator for this and your solution has the risk of corrupting the list because doOnNext and map may run concurrently due to debounce.

You could use buffer with a boundary that is triggered by the same debounced source:

```java
incomeMessageSubject
.buffer(incomingMessageSubject.debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
.subscribe(/* consume list */);
```

If your source is cold, you have to use `publish()`:

```java
source
.publish(shared -> shared.buffer(shared.debounce(1, SECONDS)))
.subscribe(/* consume list */);
```